# Disabling a menu item in Eclipse during startup

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am developing an Eclipse plugin. I need to check if the nvcc is present at start-up, and if not, then disable a particular menu item. Here is my code till now:

```
package Startup;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.eclipse.ui.IStartup;


public class StartCheck implements IStartup {

public void earlyStartup() {
    // This method checks for presence of nvcc when Eclipse starts-up.
    String command="nvcc -version";
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr;
    try {
        pr = run.exec(command);
        pr.waitFor();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        //print-out the nvcc version
        System.out.println(buf.readLine());
    }catch (IOException e) {
        //disable all buttons since no further task can be done, prompt user to install nvcc.
        System.out.println("nvcc not present, freezing the energy estimation plugin...");
        disableMenu();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
public static void disableMenu(){

}
```

}

As you can see, the disable menu method does not contain anything. Can someone please help me with this? I have to basically disable a particular menu item if an IOException occurs in the above code.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any examples from google which doesn't work and you can share the errors?

Comment: The thing is, none of them show doing this on startup. Most of them show how to disable menu items when a particular action happens. I need to do it on startup itself, which means that the code has to be in this class.

Comment: What menu item? Is it a menu you are adding (where)? Or are you trying to disable an existing menu item?

Comment: Yes, I want to disable an existing menu item.

Comment: You just need to find a particular item, have you tried the example code of finding a particular menu item and you're sure it doesn't work on startup?

Comment: I have the identifier of that particular menu item. Can't just figure-out how to do it. Can you suggest me something? (I am very new to plugin dev.).

Comment: Disabling a menu item that is not part of your code is not easy as it will have its own enablement definition.

Comment: @greg-449, can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Well, for example, if the menu item is created using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point its visibility is controlled by the `visibleWhen` part of that extension point - you can't easily override this. You might be able to do something with the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point.

Comment: The thing is, I have to do it dynamically. The method you are proposing works only when the user clicks on the particular menu item. I think I have to change the design of the task in hand itself, if I can't get a workaround.